# Why does running firebase emulators also execute one of my functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I run `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore` and get the following output:

```
$ firebase emulators:start  --only functions,firestore
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, hosting, pubsub
✔  functions: Using node@10 from host.
⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /Users/user/development/project/app/serviceKey.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/user/development/project/app/functions" for Cloud Functions...

>  TEST TEST 123

✔  functions[test-func1]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test-func1).
✔  functions[test-func2]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test-func2).
✔  functions[test-func3]: firestore function initialized.
✔  functions[test1-func1]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test1-func1).
✔  functions[test1-func2]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test1-func2).
✔  functions[test3-func1]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test3-func1).
✔  functions[test3-func2]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test3-func2).
✔  functions[test4]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project-9999d/us-east1/test4).
i  functions[test5-func1]: function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

The function is defined in `functions/scraper/index.js` as:

```js
exports.scraper = url => {
  console.log('TEST TEST', url)
  return null
}
```

It is imported and called as such in `functions/cron/index.js`

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const test = require('../scraper')

const schedule = `every 6 hours`
exports.testFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule(schedule)
  .onRun(test.scraper('123'))
```

How come I see `TEST TEST 123` output from this function but not my other functions? How can I avoid this function being executed when running emulators?

I am trying to test a scheduled cron function locally but it keeps being executed when emulators are run.

Comment: How about turning it into an arrow function: `.onRun(()=>test.scraper('123'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `.onRun(test.scraper('123'))` you are asking `pubsub` to run the **returned value** of `test.scraper('123')`. That's why the function is called during environment initialization.

If you want to run `test.scraper('123')` every 6 hours, you have to wrap it into a function.

```js
exports.testFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule(schedule)
  .onRun(() => test.scraper('123'))
```

To be more clear:

```js
exports.testFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule(schedule)
  .onRun(scheduledFunction)

function scheduledFunction() {
  test.scraper('123')
}
```

Comment: The second part of your answer is what I already have. I'm confused.

Comment: Maybe you have `.onRun(scheduledFunction())` instead of `.onRun(scheduledFunction)`.

Comment: Ohhh didn't even notice. Thanks!